# Save the value of the query in variable using node-postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I try to save the value of a query using postgres.

```
id =
    client
    .query('SELECT "ID" FROM "Test" WHERE "Name" = $1', [req.body.name])
    .then(res => {
        if (res.rows.length > 0) {
            return res.rows[0].ID;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    })
    .catch(e => {

    })
    .finally(() => {
        client.end();
    })

console.log(id);
```

Doing that, I see in the `console.log()` a `[object Promise]`.

But I want the value in that variable. So `0` if the query returns nothing or the `ID` if the query has a return.

How can I get these values instead of an `[object Promise]` object?

Comment: On a different matter I strongly advise not to allow random queries via javascript.

Comment: @Lain: I have APIs, so the above query will be used when the call from the client side is e.g. /API/getID

Comment: using async/await like this: `id = await client.query('select ...')...`